# How do I reconnect with a company that I rejected earlier?

Tags: job-change

I was job hunting for the last few months and finally accepted what was the closest to my ideal job out of my options at the time. After accepting, I received a call from another company that I had applied to earlier. I told them that I had already accepted another job. 
Now, a couple of months into my new job, it's far from what I expected and I don't think I'd like to continue beyond my probationary period. Now,

1. Is it appropriate to contact that second company? They're still hiring for a similar position.
2. If I do contact them, how do I explain the situation? Would I seem unreliable if I tell them the truth?

Answer (score 2):

Contact them, ask if they are still interested.

If at some point they ask you why you have changed your mind, have a good explanation ready for how that job differed from your expectations, and why you didn't realise until you got there.

The worst that can happen is that they say no (which could have happened the first time too), in which case you still have your current job.

The fact that another company hired you is a point in your favour; clearly they had no problem hiring you. You should be fine as long as you can confidently answer qualms about why you found out that it wasn't for you until after you joined.

Comment: Crucial point is to have good explanation what went wrong, and why this situation will not be repeated (what you learned from the experience).